# Can I start a background process with a specific working directory?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, background-process, cwd

Say I have this structure

```
/masterscript
/a/script1
/a/b/script2
```

In masterscript I spawn the other scripts as background processes:

```
"/a/script1" &
"/a/b/script2" &
```

The problem is that script1 and script2 inherit the working directory of masterscript. Is there a way to start these scripts with working directories the directories where they are?

Comment: Why not? Change the working directory to whatever you want and then start the script. `cd /a/ && ./script1`. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(cd /a   && ./script1)&
(cd /a/b && ./script2)&
```

If the names don't contain spaces or special characters like `*`, `(`, or `)`,
you don't need quotes.

Comment: I'd recommend the form `( cd /foo && exec ./script ) &`. Otherwise you leave a shell laying around for every single one of these.